# Hive UDF to convert binary(utf8) into Base64 string

Tags: java, utf-8, hive, base64, parquet

I have a binary thrift field stored in a parquet file. Parquet writes it as binary (UTF8) and I want to convert this into Base64 String using a Hive UDF. It should be very basic but don't know why my code doesn't work, here's what I've tried,

```
 public class Base64Encode extends UDF {
  public Text evaluate(Text bin) {
    if (bin != null) {
      String encoded = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(bin.getBytes()));
      if (encoded != null) {
        return new Text(encoded);
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to create your own UDF for this task. There are several already defined. In your question you say that Parquet is storing the data as a Binary, but your example code has a parameter of type Text.

If your parameter is already in binary, just use:

```
base64(bin_field)
```

Otherwise, if it is in text format and you want to convert it to Binary UTF-8 then to base 64, combine:

```
base64(encode(text_field, 'UTF-8'))
```